# Restoring state not working when returning to activity, savedInstanceState is null

Tags: java, android

So im having some trouble restoring the state of my `Activity`.
At this point I figure that its probably a problem with my understanding rather then anything else.

My goal is to move from my `MainActivity` to a `Main2Activity`.
Am I correct in thinking that when a user moves from one page to another, it should be done by changing `Activity` via `Intent`?
I am doing this like so:

The `onCreate()` for my `MainActivity` has this in it.

```
Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
currentButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
        }
    }
);
```

Which as I understand should call `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` for Main2Activity, then `onSaveInstanceState()` for `MainActivity`, then `onStop()` for `MainActivity`.
Ive overloaded all those functions with logging and seen that indeed they are being called and in that order.

Here is my `onSaveInstanceState()` for `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("onSaveInstanceState called, saving state");
    savedInstanceState.putInt("mySuperUniqueKey", testInt);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Once in `Main2Activity`, I return back to `MainActivity` in the same way. I.e. findViewById() the button, overload its `onClickListener()`, create a new `Intent` and start it.

Then `MainActivity` class's `onCreate()` has this :

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    System.out.println("savedInstanceState is not null");
    testInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("mySuperUniqueKey");
} else {
    System.out.println("savedInstanceState is null");
}
```

When returning back the `MainActivity` from `Main2Activity`, I can see from the logging that `onCreate()`, `then onStart()`, then `onResume()` for `MainActivity` is called, then `onStop()` for `Main2Activity`. Unfortunatly the logging shows that `savedInstanceState` always comes back as null.

To add to this, when in the emulator, switching the orientation back and forth causes this to work perfectly; `savedInstanceState` is not null and features the saved testInt.
Thus I figure its a problem with my understanding and that there must be something im missing.

My gradle has minSdkVersion set to 16, and targetSdkVersion set to 28. Am I maybe targeting too low a minSdkVersion?

I have read through the "Understand the Activity Lifecycle" on the official android developer documentation but still cant get it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

I did find similar problems but none of them match my situation exaclty, also the solutions they have suggested I am already doing anyway.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The saved instance state bundle is intended to save the state of the *current* activity across things like orientation changes.  It is not designed to persist across activities.  You should use `Intent#putExtra`:

```
nextIntent.putExtra("mySuperUniqueKey", testInt);
```

Then, in your next activity, access this passed value using:

```
int testInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("mySuperUniqueKey");
```